# Can't use Bytescout after adding its reference to my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, nuget

I am developing an UWP app with Visual Studio. I have installed Bytescout.Spreadsheet via Nuget, and I can see it in the references of my project as the photo below.

[image]

However, when I typed `using Bytescout.Spreadsheet`, VS just couldn't recognize it, and there was a red line under it as the photo below.

[image]

When I complied it, I encountered the following 3 errors. In English, it says "Can't find class or namespace 'Spreadsheet' (whether lost directive or reference?)

[image]

VS version: 2015

Bytescout.Spreadsheet version: 2.70.1553

I can provide further information if needed and sincerely appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What if you try to compile? What is the error if there are any? Intellisense is a bit slow to recognize new imports sometimes.

Comment: You should buy in http://bytescout.com/products/developer/barcodereadersdk/bytescoutbarcodereadersdk.html

Comment: @Lovy Please check the update.

Comment: Build the solution and check the output window for and build warnings that appear, it might show a problem with the reference to the ByteScout assemblies.

Comment: @DaveShaw Hi, all the errors have been listed in the problem description, and no warnings appeared.

Comment: @DavidChen **Bart** has already given an answer, but you would have been able to see errors about the reference in the "Output" window, not the "Errors" window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bytescout.Spreadsheet NuGet package is **NOT** compatible with Windows 10 UWP since it only provides .NET 2.0 and 4.0 packages, no WinRT or portable class libraries. For more explanation, please read my reply on [Using WPF dll's in UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477450/using-wpf-dlls-in-uwp-app/34479037#34479037) (same goes for controls and regular .NET code).

If you look at the package in [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer), you get this:

[image: Package content]

A compatible library has to support one of the win8/win8.1, uap or .netstandard1.0 (up to 1.4, after the 2017 Fall Creators Update 2.0) profiles. You can check a full list of profiles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks).

---

A possible solution here is have a web/cloud service as the backend for your application, send a request to that service to create/modify the Excel file and download the result back to your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information! I only need to read specific columns based on column names of .xlsx files, and before turning to web backend, I would like to use some local libraries to accomplish this. However, I only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281454/reading-and-writing-on-excel-from-uwp) solution available for uwp. May I ask you if you know there is a open-source library that can work now? (because the solution was provided six months ago)

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to ask for a library ([see nr 4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) and my first google searches only finds paying libraries (SyncFusion, ComponentOne, ..), so can't help you much there.
Your initial questions was a good one though and I hope I've helped you to understand why it can't work.

Comment: Yeah I now know why it can't work now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ByteScout Spreadsheet SDK is not compatible with UWP yet. But there is [ByteScout Cloud API](https://secure.bytescout.com/cloudapi.html) that provides Web API powered by ByteScout and starts at much lower pricing ($9.99/month).
There .NET client SDK is available or you may just call Web API methods directly.

*Disclosure: I'm affiliated with ByteScout*

Comment: That's also an affordable option, and I will consider about it, thanks!