# Exporting list data to an excel document in UWP

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, uwp

I have a UWP app that I am developing in Visual Studio. It successfully makes api calls and returns data. So far I have only bound this data to grid views for displaying. Now however I would like to add a "save" function that will export this data to an excel document.

Any thoughts on how I could go about this ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could create your own code that would literally take the datagrid or datatable if you are using it, use a lambda expression with one line of code and export that data to a .txt or .csv file there are plenty of examples especially on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void button_SAVE(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
    // creating Excel Application  
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();  
    // creating new WorkBook within Excel application  
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);  
    // creating new Excelsheet in workbook  
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;  
    // see the excel sheet behind the program  
    app.Visible = true;  
    // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.  
    // store its reference to worksheet  
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];  
    worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;  
    // changing the name of active sheet  
    worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";  
    // storing header part in Excel  
    for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++) 
    {  
        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;  
    }  
    // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {  
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {  
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();  
    }  
}  
// save the application  
workbook.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);  
// Exit from the application  
app.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you NOT to use excel directly, but use a different approach; try to get a nuget package to do the work for you (handling excel etc). Excel itself (as interop library) is a pain in the proverbial but cheeks.

A good one : https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

You can still use the same data you get for your grid, but export it to excel. There are numerous examples to be found for above mentioned EPPLus.

Answer (score 0):

See Sunteen's reply in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281454/reading-and-writing-on-excel-from-uwp). There are exist libraries which can do this.(Example [doc](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/uwp))

If you want to create csv yourself, there is a [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt683802.aspx) about parsing CSV.